# Inkscape : Export as pdf results in blank files

Tags: inkscape, pdf, export

I used to edit and sign pdf forms using Inkscape 0.91 on Ubuntu. For the past 2 weeks, I have been unable to do it.

I can import and embed pdf files in Inkscape, add text and paths, but when exporting, only the original embedded image would show.

I then tried to boil this down to a minimal example. Opened an empty file, wrote some text, exported it as pdf. All it did was creating a blank pdf file.

I tried to export with different options, tried to "print to file", moved elements to a new layer and even opened the pdf with a different pdf reader (evince and okular). Nothing works.

What can have gone wrong?

[image: a]

Here is the options menu I get when exporting through `file > save as`

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately I can't replicate this problem. PDFs save just fine in Inkscape 0.92. Make sure you are using the latest version of Inkscape.

Comment: IMHO, the latest LTS version of Ubuntu is 18.04, where Inkscape 0.92 is the current version. Maybe you can update your system.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm unsure exactly how you are exporting as PDF, but I found a possible issue you might have with the text.*

This is how I export the file
`file -> Save as -> Change type to PDF -> Check options -> OK`
[image: Options for PDF export]

You can check in case you selected `Omit text in PDF and create a LaTeX file` option, in which case you won't get the text in the saved PDF

---

I'm using Inkscape 0.92 on Windows.

PS: With incomplete information about the question, I'm unsure if this answer is useful. I was going to post this as a comment but don't have enough reputation. 
You might find some useful answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5880/how-to-export-an-inkscape-svg-file-to-a-pdf-and-maintain-the-integrity-of-the-im)

Comment: Thanks Prashant! I export the way you do, but I have no such option in the menu. I'll edit my question to add info.

Comment: I also got it to work in 0.92.4 in Ubuntu. Did you try updating your version?

Comment: No, I can't upgrade to 18.04 because I mixed up things with virtualenv. I'll have to reinstall ubuntu, I'll let you know if it worked when I have.