# Inkscape import PDF / save as PDF results in nearly blank page

Tags: inkscape, pdf, file-conversion

I'm trying out Inkscape to edit some PDF files.  The tool seems to work well, the interface is understandable, usable, and when I'm in the document, things look fine.

However when I go to save the document as a PDF, the result is nearly a blank page.  When I look at the result saved PDF closely (and scroll up and down), I can barely discern some hints of gray that indicate the content is there but colored wrong.

Its like watching a polar bear snowball fight during a winter storm.  At first couple of glances you'd think the output was just blank.

[image: Polar Bear Snow Fight White on White PDF document]

One odd note:  When I export the document page as a PNG Image, it looks great.  Black text on white background, as expected.

I'm using Inkscape ver 1.0.1 on Windows 10 (ver 20H2)  My issue is NOT the same that as identified in [this posting.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/134991/inkscape-export-as-pdf-results-in-blank-files)

What is causing this virtually all white PDF output?

Comment: Pics or it didnt happen ;)

Comment: @joojaa   Photo attached.  I will say, Until I scrolled up and down a few times I didn't even notice the slight bits of gray.